# Remove ceiling lamp holder to change light bulb

Tags: ceiling, lamp

I have a ceiling lamp (shown in attached picture) mounted in my bathroom. I want to remove the lid and change the light bulb inside and replace the lid. However, I am struggling to remove it. 
There are three black holders (clamps). One of them feels like a spring plugged in and has an arrow pointing outward. I tried pulling it out but it doesn’t release the grip on the lid. The other two black clamps don’t budge either. I tried rotating it, applying pressure to the center to life the glass a bit higher but nothing seems to work. Anybody have any ideas? I live in Germany and presumably this was purchased in Ikea but i can’t find the product in their website.
[image]

Comment: maybe the arrow on the clip indicates that the glass should be pushed in that direction ... that would disengage it from the other two clips

Comment: Hey thanks. That worked. I can mark it as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow on the clip can also indicate that the glass diffuser should be pushed in the direction of the arrow.

That would cause the diffuser to disengage from the other two clips.

Comment: I find it *easier and safer* to support the glass with one hand and  then grasp the spring loaded clip with the other. Pull the spring loaded clip out/away then lower the glass down and away from the other two clips.

Comment: The spring clip may be too stiff and small to grab and move by itself @AlaskaMan

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  possibly , but I changed one exactly like it three days ago in the manner that I described.